# MVN not finding tests

Tags: unit-testing, maven

When running `mvn clean install`, once we get to Test section, i see

```
-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------

Results :

Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
```

My surefire plugin is configured as follows:

```
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <testFailureIgnore>false</testFailureIgnore>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*Test*.java</include>
                </includes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Test file names follow this format. For instance `A.java` has `ATest.java` as it's test

Directory structure from which `mvn clean install` is ran is standard

```
├── src
│   ├── main
│   │   ├── java
│   │   │   └── ***
│   └── test
│       └── java
│           └── ***
```

Individual Tests are annotated with `@Test` and

```
import org.junit.Test;
```

Further more test names follow convention of

```
public void testSomething() throws Exception
```

In a spirit of completeness, below is my pom

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"
         xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>a.b.c</groupId>
    <artifactId>My_Project</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>JBOSS_NEXUS</id>
            <url>http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <build>
        <finalName>My_Project</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
                <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.7.4</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1.1</version>
                <extensions>false</extensions>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <vesion></vesion>
                <configuration>
                    <testFailureIgnore>false</testFailureIgnore>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/*Test*.java</include>
                    </includes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>cobertura-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <formats>
                        <format>xml</format>
                        <format>html</format>
                    </formats>
                    <check/>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>clean</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>cobertura</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <reporting>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>cobertura-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </reporting>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.8.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            ...
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

What am i missing please?

Comment: Please include the source of a small test that isn't being found. How are they annotated? What test framework are you using?

Comment: I have a feeling that your `<include>` pattern might be the reason. Try to remove this section and see if any tests are run.

Comment: @AndrewLogvinov Tried it, Does not seem to help

Comment: Well, can you post your pom.xml file? It seems we need to look at it altogether. Also, check out build output. Are tests compiled?

Comment: probably a cut&paste issue but it is strange to have this `<vesion></vesion>` in your `maven-surefire-plugin` section

Comment: can you run mvn test -X and post the output ?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to help if the information is as scattered as it is. You probably can not or do not want to disclose more, so we have to work with what we see.

One differences to my usual code is that the `<scope>` is `test` in

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.8.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Additionally each test method needs to be annotated with `@Test`, not the class. It may be what you meant, but the language is a little ambiguous here.

Since you are using the default setup, location and naming for tests you can completely remove the `maven-surefire-plugin` section.

You might need to tell maven that you want to use Java 1.6:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: I tried all steps listed above, same problem .. what else could it be?

Comment: Try using mvn -X to get extra diagnostics and try to run a single test individually (check the maven documentation on how to do it). You can also try to open/recreate your project with Netbeans and see if the IDE can give you any hint.